# 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'tree_' error using graphviz

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz

I'm using a gridsearchCV to set parameters for a decision tree regressor as below.

```
    clf = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=99),parameters,refit=True,cv=5)  # default is MSE
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I then want to pass this output a chart using Graphviz

```
    export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot',feature_names=df_temp.columns,leaves_parallel=True)
    subprocess.call(['dot', '-Tpdf', 'tree.dot', '-o' 'tree.pdf'])
```

I'm getting an error message however:
'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'tree_'

I'm really stuck with this and could do with some help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export_graphviz expects DecisionTreeRegressor, not GridSearchCV; try using `export_graphviz(clf.best_estimator_, ...)`.